# How to verify Python mock calls with generator argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, generator

I have a function that takes an `Iterable` as an argument:

```
def print_me(vals: Iterable[str]) -> None:
    ...
```

It gets called with a generator:

```
def run():
    print_me((str(i) for i in range(10)))
```

I'd like to patch and mock `print_me()` and verify it gets called with specific parameters. With plain old lists, this is easy:

```
mock.assert_called_with(["0", "1", ...])
```

but with a generator, because it can't be matched on equality or replayed, this is trickier.

Answer (score 4):

I found a few solutions. I can manually capture the argument, but it gets messier if the method is called more than once:

```
@patch('module.print_me')
def test(self, mock):
    captured = None
    mock.side_effect = lambda vals: captured = vals
    run()    
    mock.assert_called_once_with(mock.ANY)
    self.assertEqual(list(captured), ["0", "1", ...])
```

I can also proxy the mock. This makes assertions clean, but is a bit weird to think about, and the `proxy()` function needs to be updated every time the real function's arguments change.

```
@patch('module.print_me')
def test(self, proxy_mock):
    mock = mock.Mock()
    def proxy(vals):
        mock(list(vals))

    proxy_mock.side_effect = proxy

    run()    
    mock.assert_called_once_with(["0", "1"])
    mock.assert_called_once_with(["2", "3"])
```

There's also PyHamcrest. Hamcrest is really popular with Java tests, but doesn't seem to be as popular for Python. That said, it does what I want:

```
@patch('module.print_me')
def test(self, mock):
    run()
    mock.assert_called_once_with(match_equality(contains_exactly(["2", "3"])))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to test this, and that is by using the the [`call_args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args) attribute of the mock object. `call_args` returns a tuple where the first item is the `args` and the second item is the `kwargs`. The syntax was slightly changed in Python 3.8 to allow for accessing these items by doing `mock_object.call_args.args` or `mock_object.call_args.kwargs` but I am running this on Python 3.7 so I am taking the more antiquated approach.

```
@patch("src.module.print_me")
def test_run(mock_print):
    run()
    args, _ = mock_print.call_args
    # grab the one and only call argument
    gen = args[0]
    expected = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
    
    assert list(gen) == expected
```

As you can see in the code snippet above, we grab the argument that was fed in to our mock object, consume it and then compare it against the expected value.